# problems plotting two different SVMs approaches with matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I would like to muck up two different approaches of a classification algorithm as this [documentation example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html). This is what I tried:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False, ngram_range=(2,2))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/data.csv',
                     header=0, sep=',', names=['SentenceId', 'Sentence', 'Sentiment'])



X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['Sentence'].values)
y = df['Sentiment'].values


from sklearn import cross_validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,
                                                    y, test_size=0.33)
from sklearn.svm import SVC
#first svm
clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(reduced_data, y)
prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-10, 10)
yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]


# get the separating hyperplane using weighted classes

#second svm
wclf = SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight={5: 10},C=1000)
wclf.fit(reduced_data, y)
weighted_prediction = wclf.predict(X_test)



#PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)


ww = wclf.coef_[0]
wa = -ww[0] / ww[1]
wyy = wa * xx - wclf.intercept_[0] / ww[1]

# plot separating hyperplanes and samples
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h0 = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-', label='no weights')
h1 = plt.plot(xx, wyy, 'k--', label='with weights')
plt.scatter(reduced_data[:, 0], reduced_data[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.legend()

plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 25, in <module>
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 253, in __getitem__
    return self._get_row_slice(row, col)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 320, in _get_row_slice
    raise IndexError('index (%d) out of range' % i)
IndexError: index (1) out of range
```

How can I plot this task correctly in 2-D  or 3-D with matplotlib?. I also tried this, but clearly this is wrong:

[image]

Thanks in advance, this is the [data](http://pastebin.com/E0zhZwhe) I am using to do this.

**When I print `w` this is what happen:**

```
     (0, 911)   -0.352103548716
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
  (0, 2346) -1.20396753467
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 253, in __getitem__
  (0, 2482) -0.352103548716
  (0, 2288) -0.733605938797
  (0, 1175) -0.868966214318
  (0, 1936) -0.500071158622
  (0, 2558) -0.40965370142
  (0, 788)  -0.485330735934
  (0, 322)  -0.575610464517
  (0, 453)  -0.584854414882
  (0, 1913) -0.300076915818
  (0, 2411) -0.419065159403
  (0, 2017) -0.407926583824
  (0, 2363) -0.407926583824
  (0, 815)  -1.09245625795
  (0, 543)  -0.248207856236
  (0, 1082) -0.366433457602
  (0, 1312) -0.286768829333
  (0, 1525) -0.286768829333
  (0, 1677) -0.286768829333
  (0, 2679) -0.688619491265
  (0, 413)  -0.101096807406
  (0, 1322) -0.13561265293
  (0, 1488) -0.120403497624
  (0, 1901) -0.337806267742
  : :
  (0, 1609) 0.100116485705
  (0, 581)  0.276579777388
  (0, 2205) 0.241642287418
  (0, 1055) 0.0166785719624
  (0, 2390) 0.349485515339
  (0, 1866) 0.357035248059
  (0, 2098) 0.296454010725
  (0, 2391) 0.45905660273
  (0, 2601) 0.357035248059
  (0, 619)  0.350880030278
  (0, 129)  0.287439419266
  (0, 280)  0.432180530894
  (0, 1747) -0.172314049543
  (0, 1211) 0.573579514463
  (0, 86)   0.3152907757
  (0, 452)  0.305881204557
  (0, 513)  0.212678772368
  (0, 946)  -0.347372778859
  (0, 1194) 0.298193025133
  (0, 2039) 0.34451957335
  (0, 2483) 0.245366213834
  (0, 317)  0.355996551812
  (0, 977)  0.355996551812
  (0, 1151) 0.284383826645
  (0, 2110) 0.120512273328
```

It returned a very large sparse matrix.

Comment: Maybe this problem live in a higher dimention. Do I need to do PCA in order to plot it?

Comment: Can you provide the data you've used in pastebin link?

Comment: @Ffisegydd Here are the shapes of the matrices: reduced_data.shape, y.shape, X_test.shape, X_train.shape they look like this respectevely: (2599, 11991) (2599,) (858, 11991) (1741, 11991)

Comment: Can you put the data back up?

Answer (score 2):

```
w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
```

It would seem your 'w' list only contains one value.  This would be the reason you are receiving an error when trying to access the second index w[1].

Comment: Any idea of how to fix this?. Thanks for the feedback. I edited

Comment: `print w` and see what value is stored.  It will need to resemble `[number, number]` for your current `a = -w[0] / w[1]` to not error out.

Comment: I couldnt print the shape of w, I tried printing this:`reduced_data.shape, y.shape, X_test.shape, X_train.shape` they look like this respectevely: `(2599, 11991)
(2599,)
(858, 11991)
(1741, 11991)`

Comment: You should be able to `w = clf.coef_[0]` `print w` `a = -w[0] / w[1]` to show what is stored in 'w' before it errors out on the next line.  Your data *must* have two values to divide as per the line `a = -w[0] / w[1]`.  If the second value you've shown above `(2599,)` is used, there will be an error.  I would verify the values before attempting the math.

Comment: Sorry I got confused in which line was the error, I edited the question. When I print w it returned a very large sparse matrix

Answer (score 2):

If w is a sparse matrix, you have to access it as such. Try:

```
a = -w[0,0] / w[0, 1]
```

Although I have to warn you: the example you are following for visualization is of a very simple 2D problem. For the visualization you have in mind to make any sense at all, you would have to perform dimensionality reduction (such as PCA) before visualizing the problem. While you can obviously plot the first 2 coordinates of your 12k dimensions, the chances of these happening to be the most informative dimensions is virtually 0.

EDIT: looking at your `w` matrix, this will still not work, but at least now it should give a division by zero problem, rather than an index out of range. Thinking about it a bit more, I am not quite sure how to solve your problem. If your aim is to visualize your data, you can use PCA to reduce your data to 2D first, and then run an SVM to find a separator (with and without weights), but it is unlikely that your SVM parameters will generalize to your actual problem. On the other hand, you can run your SVM in the higher dimension and use this to color your solution in your PCA. The best case, this will give you two fairly well separated coloured groups: in this case your SVM is working really well, and PCA maintains most of the structure of your problem. However, if one of these two conditions does not hold (and particularly the latter is unlikely to hold for most problems), you will get an almost random pattern in your colours. In this case you cannot really draw any conclusions at all.

EDIT 2: I have written a short script for extracting 2 PCA dimensions and plotting them for you. Note that I don't reduce to 2, I reduce to 10000, and then extract the first 2. In practice it doesn't make a lot of difference (my code is less efficient), but this way it allows me to illustrate a point: if you reduce to 10,000 dimensions you lose no representative power, meaning you have about 2k useless dimensions (or more, didn't try to reduce the PCA further). However, reducing to 2 goes far too far: then you are left with a power of 0.07, which is far too low to do anything much useful with. As you see in the plot. Note that if you zoom in something fierce on the plot, there seems to be a linear correlation between the first 2 components of your PCA reduction. Unfortunately I am not a good enough statistician to tell you what that means. If I had to take a guess, I would say that you have quite a bit of covariance in your data, but this is a total stab in the dark.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False, ngram_range=(2,2))

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('corpus.txt',
                     header=0, sep=',', names=['SentenceId', 'Sentence', 'Sentiment'])



X = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['Sentence'].values)
y = df['Sentiment'].values


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=10000)
reduced = pca.fit_transform(X.toarray())
print sum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_)
print pca.explained_variance_ratio_[0] + pca.explained_variance_ratio_[1]

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

by_class = {}
for i in range(0, len(y)):
  if not y[i] in by_class:
    by_class[y[i]] = []
  by_class[y[i]].append(reduced[i])

for c in by_class:
  toplt = np.array(by_class[c]).T
  plt.plot(toplt[0], toplt[1], linestyle='', marker='o')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot generated by above code]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Acrofales. This is what I got with your solution:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "l.py", line 26, in <module>
    yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 253, in __getitem__
    return self._get_row_slice(row, col)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 320, in _get_row_slice
    raise IndexError('index (%d) out of range' % i)
IndexError: index (1) out of range`

Comment: I also tried with pca but the performance of the svm was bad (i.e. all the metrics fall down)

Comment: This is with PCA: `from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)` from here any idea of how to plot it?

Comment: In the new version, can you please print w, and also the shape of w? I think `w` is probably still a sparse matrix, and you have to acess it with `w[0, 1]`. Regarding the SVM after PCA: it's expected that your SVM will perform badly on your heavily reduced data. It is unlikely you can reduce from 11k dimensions to 2 without a significant loss of information and separability. But your aim is to visualize your data, right? Simply accept that the SVM won't work as well, but you will be able to plot your (possibly meaningless) data. What is the power of your PCA (sum of the first 2 eigen values)?

Comment: Thanks for the help @Acrofales. I edited the question and update `w`. Still can not figure out how to plot this. How can I compute the power of the eigen values?.

Comment: @ml_guy: `w` is still a sparse matrix then, and despite it being a column vector, you have to access it as a matrix: `w[0, 1]` to get the 2nd element in your vector. The power of your reduction is equal to the sum of the eigen values corresponding to the eigen vectors that you are using. So, when you reduce to 2 dimensions, the power is the sum of the first 2 eigen values. If you're using sklearn to do your PCA, these values are stored in `explained_variance_ratio_`.

Comment: pff... I am stuck Probably this task is not possible to plot. @Acrofales, thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, but this one didn't really deserve it. I am editing in a bit more useful stuff. Specifically, the code for plotting the PCA. Note, however, that the PCA reduction to 2 dimensions is completely meaningless: the representative power with respect to the original answer is 0.07 (which means that ~7% of the variance in the original space is explained by the variance in these 2 dimensions). In general, I agree with your final conclusion: while not impossible to plot, it does not help you better understand the problem. What were you trying to figure out with your plot?

Comment: I would like to plot how does the hyper plane behaves as the [example in the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html). Thanks for the support

Comment: Yeah, but seeing as visualization in this higher dimension is probably not the best approach, what are you trying to understand about your solution or problem by plotting how the hyperplane behaves? Hrm. By now we are probably reaching into stats.stackexchange.com content. Might be best to think of that question and post it there.

Comment: I would like to see just as a practice (im an undergrad student) how this problem look and how the hyperplanes classify any other idea of how can I visualize this?.

Comment: Honestly, if you are trying to understand how SVM (or any other ML algorithm for that matter) works by visualizing it, you are best sticking to 2D or 3D problems. That will give you the basic "feeling" for the algorithm, and also help you to understand the cost function that it uses. Once you understand that you can better understand this cost function in higher dimensions and use it directly (as well as a whole scala of other metrics) to evaluate how well the method is working on your high-dimensional problem. Is this specific data set important to you?

Comment: Thanks for the support, sure since I have been working with this data.